# Mounting Azure Data lake Gen2 with Databricks /mnt

Tags: azure, blob, storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have mounted my Azure Data lake Gen2 with Databricks and the mount was done successfully. The problem is that I got this error ( FileNotFoundException: / is not found ).
This is my command using Scala to mount.

```
**###
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://XXXXXXXX@YYYYYYYYYYYY.blob.core.windows.net", 
  mountPoint = "/mnt/",
  extraConfigs = Map("fs.azure.sas.XXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYYYY.blob.core.windows.net" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "SCOPENAME", key = "SCOPEKEY")))
###**
```

I have created the Scope secrets in data bricks and linked them with Blob storage in Azure.

I am also executing this command :

```
dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "SCOPENAME", key = "SCOPEKEY")
```

and I am getting that they are mounted :
String = [REDACTED]

What was something wrong I did?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you run this command `%fs ls /mnt` ? Check the results you're getting

Comment: You have great documentation. Follow it.  Before you start,  figure out if you are using ADLS or not.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the location based on the following comments . For DBFS location understanding [link](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#access-files-on-dbfs)

```
%fs ls /mnt
```

or

```
%sh ls /dbfs/tmp/
```

or

```
dbutils.fs.ls ("/mnt/")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to execute all these commands, and I got this error always .   
FileNotFoundException: / is not found

Comment: Is there something I have to add in Azure Data lake Gen2? for example, Rights rules ....etc